# Apollo in memory cache configurations

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am using graphQL and apollo-in-memory cache to display rows in a table. In some views there is a reasonable amount of data (100s of records) and for calls like this I want to cache the results. On a different view of the page there are too many results (100,000+) and using the Apollo cache negatively affects performance. The page becomes slow and laggy, and when i use the Apollo chrome extension I get this console warning

```
Apollo DevTools serialized state is 42.6 MB. This may cause performance degradation.
```

It became more performant for this page to skip the cache entirely. Are there any client side configurations to take more direct control of the cache?

thank you

Comment: Maybe you are puling in lot's of data for UI parts that the user hasn't opened yet? If that's the case you could consider requesting that data only when the user decided to open that part of the UI.

Comment: the table has a total count and allows for client side  filtering and sorting. So I am nervous that if we only fetch 20% of the data at at a time, those features will not produce accurate results

Answer (score 0):

First you should try again with the production build.
This warning you get and the performance degragation might well come from the dev tools that will render and monitor cache entries.
Production might handle these many entries fine.

The clean solution for this would be to use pagination to only load the as many entries as the UI shows at a time.
ApolloClient has some build in support for that:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/core-api

A quick solution would be to not use the cache for this query with 100k results by using `fetchPolicy: no-cache`:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/advanced-topics/#bypassing-the-cache